# How to use eloquent on the auth command user in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am facing a weird error right now

In my controller, when I import the class user like this

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

It works when I use eloquent like

```
public function index()

    {

        $farms = User::where('role_id', 3)->get();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('clinic.index', compact('user', 'animal', 'farms'));
    }
```

But refuses to work when it comes to table relationships like

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $farms = User::with(['animals'])->findOrFail($id);
        return view('clinic.show',compact('farms'));
    }
```

showing me this error

```
"Call to undefined relationship [animals] on model [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User]"
```

But whenever I import the user class as App\User in my controller,

It works in the relationship but refuses to work with the eloquent showing this error

```
"Call to a member function get() on null"
```

Now I am kinda confused. Any help will be welcomed

App\User

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public static function where(string $string, int $int)
    {
    }

    public static function select(array $array)
    {
    }

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
    public function animals(){
        return $this->hasMany(Animal::class);
    }

    public function clinics(){
        return $this->hasMany(Clinic::class);
    }

    public function slaughter(){
        return $this->hasMany(Slaughter::class);
    }

    public function address(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: You again! use App\User is what you should be using.  Post up your User model please.

Comment: It should not be an array

Comment: @FAKETAXI How am I making my elequent work then

Comment: @onlineThomas what should not be an array?

Comment: @FAKETAXI I did everything as you said and it was working but when I went back one step before, I realised this case now

Comment: @onlineThomas 90% sure arrays are acceptable here, as you can pass multiple relationships through with() --- but I suppose it's worth trying without.  Remove your square brackets from ```User::with(['animals'])``` is what Thomas is saying

Comment: @onlineThomas https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading  -- array isn't the issue

Comment: My bad, thought you than had to provide a callable as value (associative array)

Comment: I donnot get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` class is the parent of the `App\User` class and `animals` relation set in the `App\User`class. So you can't call `animals` relation from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` class.

You should remove these functions from the `App\User` Model:

```php
public static function where(string $string, int $int)
{
}

public static function select(array $array)
{
}
```

Comment: So How am I supposed to do this cause the 'where' eloquent is not working with the App\User

Comment: @lmmeyti I have added it

Comment: @Jimmyjbk Updated my answer.